# Why am I only getting a response where readyState is 4?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have done a simple example wherein I am trying to print a response into the HTML of a `<div>` as the state changes from 2 to 4. But somehow I am getting a response for only 4. Why is that?

```js
function func() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 2) {
      document.getElementById("resp").innerHTML = "Response 2";
    } else if (this.readyState == 3) {
      document.getElementById("resp").innerHTML = "Response 3";
    } else(this.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById("resp").innerHTML = "Response 4 : " + this.responseText;
    }

  }
  xhr.open("GET", "back.php", true);
  xhr.send();
}
```

```html
<div id="resp"></div>
<input type="submit" onclick="func()" name="name" value="name" id="name">
```

Comment: `else(this.readyState==4)` The `else` statement cannot have a condition in it. It should be `else if (this.readyState==4)`.

Comment: `else(this.readyState == 4)` is a syntax error. If you _overwrite_ `.innerHTML` instead of appending it with `+=`, you will only see the last result, as the states transition too quickly.

Comment: @Vivek changed the `else` condition to `else if` but still no response.

Comment: @Xufox would you be kind enough to tell me how to execute `+=` in the code. Although I have got your point. Checked by making 3 separate `<div>` and it s working. But please tell me how to use `+=` and make it work with one `<div>` itself. Thanks man!

Comment: Just replace `.innerHTML =` by `.innerHTML +=`.

Comment: @Xufox Replaced `+` with `+=` in all the 3 code blocks but the output is a not what I desire. `Response 4 : Response 2Response 4 : Response 3Response 4 : hello world Response 4 : hello world` I know it is all formatting but being new to the whole thing it would be really nice if you could help me out with it. Tried removing `Response 4` and removing the `+` in the last code block but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Don'tDownvoteMe Try actually using `else if(this.readyState == 4)`.

Comment: @Xufox Thanks a lot man! it works just fine. But why is that that when we use `else`, the response goes haywire?

Comment: Try to use the console, and just `console.log(this.readyState);`.

Comment: @Xufox Thanks again!

Comment: @Vivek Thanks man!